# Why does some armor have both Hull Points and Damage Reduction?

Tags: damage-reduction, planet-mercenary

All armors within the game of *Planet Mercenary* sport some degree of Damage Reduction, which reduces incoming damage.

> **Damage Reduction**: Each time you suﬀer
>   damage while wearing the armor, reduce the
>   damage by this amount. Some attacks may
>   have the ability to ignore Damage Reduction.

Some armor also has Hull Points

> Some of the heaviest armor also provides you
>   with 1 Hull Point (Hull) of protection. This is
>   equivalent to the lightest raw protection on a
>   space vessel, and it blocks all physical damage
>   until an enemy frst punches through that layer
>   (some exceptions exist to this rule, as noted
>   for various attacks). An attack that inﬂicts any
>   amount of hull damage destroys a suit of armor,
>   including one oﬀering one or more Hull Points
>   of protection. In a suit of armor oﬀering hull
>   protection you can withstand a single attack that
>   inﬂicts hull damage, but afer that the armor is
>   destroyed and you’re eﬀectively not wearing
>   armor at all.

This armor also has Damage Reduction, despite that any weapon that doesn't do Hull damage doesn't do any damage and a weapon that does Hull damage totally destroys the armor. So, where does the DR come in?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Errata](https://www.planetmercenary.com/assets/sm/upload/qe/ba/99/wd/PM%20Errata.pdf) for the product provides some guidance:

> Armor has damage reduction listed even when it also has hull points, because some weapons bypass armor defense, thus requiring a simulation of armor adding "extra health" and the ability to "reduce damage", all in one package.

Alan Bahr, the designer, [says](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1445604298891148/permalink/1458509214267323/?comment_id=1458555914262653&reply_comment_id=1458597950925116&notif_id=1511030460411377&notif_t=group_comment_reply) that while there is no weapon that currently bypasses Hull Points but targets DR, they reserve the right to add in such a weapon later, so they wanted to establish what would happen in that case.

[image: Alan's response, transcribed below]

> The intent here is this:
>
> Hull Points block all damage.
>   Eventually we might release a weapon quality that "ignores Hull Points", but we still want Armor Reduction to apply. In order to accomplish that, we preemptively included this text.
>
> As of now, there are no rules that Ignore HP awhile allowing Armor Reduction to apply. It's all or nothing.
>
> If your Armor has HP, you can't be hurt until a weapon does 1 HP worth of damage. Once that happens, your armor is trashed and you get no benefit from it. Armor Reduction doesn't apply.

Comment: Can I +1 the authors, too, for forward thinking? ;)