# How does armor with Hull Points function against AVPL weapons?

Tags: damage-reduction, planet-mercenary

This was an interesting point brought up on the Facebook group wherein Alan Bahr [was invoked](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1445604298891148/permalink/1469202106531367/?comment_id=1469813466470231&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R%22%7D) to rule upon it. By the book, weapons capable of doing Hull damage will simply obliterate anything they go up against that doesn't have Hull Points (something generally restricted to spaceships). However, [some armor has at least 1 Hull Point and also has DR](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110171/why-does-some-armor-have-both-hull-points-and-damage-reduction?rq=1).

> Some of the heaviest armor also provides you
>   with 1 Hull Point (Hull) of protection. This is
>   equivalent to the lightest raw protection on a
>   space vessel, and it blocks all physical damage
>   until an enemy first punches through that layer
>   (some exceptions exist to this rule, as noted
>   for various attacks). An attack that inflicts any
>   amount of hull damage destroys a suit of armor,
>   including one offering one or more Hull Points
>   of protection.

The question which comes up is how this interacts with the AVPL (Anti-Vehicular PayLoad) quality on some weapons.

> This weapon can damage large objects and vehicles that have hull points (see page
>   vehicular Payload) 147). When an attack with this weapon hits a target with Hull Points, the target loses
>   1 Hull Point. This may destroy the source of the target’s Hull Points, such as a suit
>   of heavy armor. Against any target without Hull Points, roll the weapon’s listed
>   damage as normal.

Especially using the Custom Armor rules, it is possible to have armor with high DR (Damage Reduction), but no Hull Points, which leads to the odd situation where armor without Hull Points might be more useful against an AVPL payload since it will blunt some of the damage, and it can take more than one hit without becoming useless.

How exactly does one balance this out and have it make sense in the context of the system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two solutions I'd run with (pending me issuing a formal errata):

> 1.) When the APVL quality is used against a target with no Hull Points, it ignores 4 points of Damage Reduction.

Drawbacks to this one:

- More bookkeeping
- It makes AVPL half as good as the Breacher for less than half the points.

If you can live with those drawbacks, that's a good fix.

> 2.) Rewrite the AVPL text to thus: 
>   **This weapon can damage large objects and vehicles that have hull points (see page 147). When an attack with this weapon hits a target with Hull Points, the target loses 1 Hull Point. This may destroy the source of the target’s Hull Points, such as a suit of heavy armor. Against any target without Hull Points, roll the weapon’s listed damage, increased by +1d6, and giving this weapon the Armor Piercing Quality**

There's a bit more there than I'd like to introduce into the rules, but it's probably a better "balanced" revision.

EDIT: I guess I have to put references in for how I came to this solution? I wrote the game.

Comment: :) I guess I can't just keep citing you if you're writing your own words.

Answer (score 0):

[My personal take on it](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1445604298891148/permalink/1469202106531367/?comment_id=1469209069864004&reply_comment_id=1469209719863939&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R2%22%7D):

> If you wanted to keep the flavor of it, you could have the armor "cook" if hit with more than one Hull Point of damage, or roll for damage on top of the Hull Point damage and if that roll exceeds the DR, the armor "cooks".

To me, that keeps the spirit of armor with Hull Points, that normal weapons can't scratch them, still means that they will lose that armor if fired upon by a ship weapon, and that they can sometimes take more than one hit from an AVPL weapon before they lose the armor.