# How do the Goaltenders in the Golem EX armor work?

Tags: planet-mercenary

Possibly mildly related to [How does armor with Hull Points function against AVPL weapons?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110832/how-does-armor-with-hull-points-function-against-avpl-weapons)

The **Vella Tacspec T2-F11 Golem EX** comes with an **RIP-A Goaltender** that will provide DR reduction 5. The armor has Hull Points, which means non-Hull Point damage doesn't really do anything. Do the Goaltenders intercept Hull Damage attacks? Or do they effectively do nothing unless the game introduces a weapon that bypasses Hull Points but applies against DR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. I can see where this particular interaction is unclear.

As per pg. 136 in the Planet Mercenary rulebook, "An attack that inflicts any amount of hull damage destroys a suit of armor, including one offering one or more Hull Points of protection."

Keeping in mind the details in the errata (Goaltenders absorb damage first), the RAW reading is:

**Each goaltender absorbs 1 Hull damage, before being destroyed. Once all the goaltenders are gone, damage hits armor (destroying it outright if it's hull damage) and then the player (hopefully destroying them outright for such a silly interaction.)**

However, I don't like that interaction terribly much.

As Goaltenders (pg 137) are added onto existing armor and serve as team protection, I could see the situation be ruled in one of two ways:

1.) Goaltenders (being autonomous floating shields, in effect), are not destroyed by Hull damage when the armor is, thereby providing reduction even after being hit by a weapon that deals hull point damage.

**Note**: I prefer this solution, because it effectively provides a player extra levels of protection against big guns (each Goaltender effectively absorbing damage post the initial hull damage.)

2.) Goaltenders serve as an extra layer of armor, with each Goaltender absorbing 1 Hull damage before being obliterated.

**Note:** I like this solution less, as it makes Goaltenders pretty good. It shouldn't be too unbalancing, but it's a wacky interaction with these little drones absorbing giant anti-vehicular attacks, while your armor remains intact.

So in summation, my preferred solution is this:

Hull damage destroys the armor, leaving the Goaltenders to function as written, with Goaltenders providing reduction against non-Hull damage as normal.

This doesn't really relate to ["How armor w/ hull Points functions against AVPL weapons"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110171/why-does-some-armor-have-both-hull-points-and-damage-reduction?rq=1), though it might one day and if it does, I'll try to come back to update and correct this (or write the rules in such a way that it's moot.)